# (decision spreadsheet) When attribute is applied on spreadsheet it can't be converted to Decision Table

Tags: drools, rule-engine

My spreadsheet values are:

+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|       |         A          |               B                |                C                |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|  7   |**CONDITION** | **DATE-EFFECTIVE**  |            **ACTION**                 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|  8   |obj: UObject |                                  |                                   |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|  9   |x1="$param"|                                  | obj.setX2("$param");|
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| 10  |      ABCD     |       27-Apr-2018       |  EFFECTIVE NOW!  |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+

Upon uploading excel file to Decision Manager it was successful but when I tried to convert it to decision table I always encouter this error
**Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: Unexpected content "" in cell B9, leave this cell blank.**

Hoping for anyone's assistance, I can't move from this :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the attribute then create a variable on your main object named to your desired attribute then convert to Decision Table would be Successful.

+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|             |                A                  |                           B                                |                          C                                 |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|  7      |CONDITION |        **CONDITION**      |                  ACTION                    |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|  8    |            **obj: UObject**                                                        |                                                                  |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
|  9     |x1="$param"  |      **dateEffective**                                    | obj.setX2("$param");|
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| 10  |            ABCD       |            27-Apr-2018            |  EFFECTIVE NOW!  |
+----+-----------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+

Remove the Attribute **DATE-EFFECTIVE** and make it a **CONDITION** then add **dateEffective** variable on **UObject**. Once convert button is clicked it will be converted to Decision Table.